# unable to load dynamic library php_osi8.dll

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I need to connect to an Oracle database with PHP.

I downloaded & intalled the oracle `instantclient11_1` and set path in enviroment variable, but I get the following error:

> unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_osi8.dll--the specified module could not found

Answer (score 1):

please try copying the files php_osi8.dll, orannzsbb11.dll , oci.dll and oraociei11.dll to c:\windows\system32

OR

adding C:\xampp\php\ext\" to Windows PATH environment variable.  I think this is better than copying dlls which could lead to issues down the road if you end up with multiple dlls with different versions on the same machine.